# javascript associative array, looping, and / or scope issue with Highcharts JSON call

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, postgresql, highcharts

I have a javascript associative array issue, looping issue, and / or scope issue.  I'm trying to call data from a postgresql database, parse it, and implement it in a Highchart.

The data consists of five series with five items (columns / fields) each:

```
 [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

Opened, the fifth object looks like:

```
4: Object
acronym: "1"
current: "3.4"
id: 1
name: "a"
pc1: "2.5"
previous: "2.4"
url: "http://myhost:3000/series/1.json"
__proto__: Object
length: 5
__proto__: Array[0]
```

After parsing, I get a sequence of objects:

```
[Object]
[Object]
[Object]
[Object]
[Object]
```

Which consist of the parsed data expect, i.e., a k:v pair [name: "a", y: 2.5]:

```
[Object]
0: Object
name: "a"
y: 2.5
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
```

However, what I need is an array of objects:

```
[{name: "a", y: 2.5}, {name: "b", y: 3.0}, {name: "c", y: 1.0}, {name: "d", y: 2.0}, {name: "e", y: 3.2}]
```

If I insert "dummy" data - below - the chart renders correctly, so the issue's with my code, specifically, the creation of the array and its availability outside the JSON function.

```
[{name: 'name1', y: 2.5}, {name: 'name2', y: 4.0}];
```

Any and all help would be appreciated.  Here's the entire javascript code for the Highchart - with notes where the issues are.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var options = {       
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column',
        },

        title: {
            text: 'The Conference Board'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Leading Indicators '
        },

        xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                labels: {
                    rotation: -45,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                    }
                }
            },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Percent Change Year / Year'
            },
        },

        series: [{
            data: []  // dummy code inserted here makes the chart render

        }]
};

url = "http://myhost:3000/series";
$.getJSON(url, function (series) {
  console.log(series);                    // five series of five k:v pairs each

  $.each(series, function(key_i, val_i) { // parsing to a single k:v (name: value) pair

    data = [];                            // I'm trying to create an array of objects     //  [{},{},{},{},{}]
    data.push({                           // for insertion into the var     options.series.data above
      name: val_i.name,
      y: parseFloat(val_i.pc1) 
});

options.series[0].data = data;
console.log(options.series[0].data);  // getting all k:val_i pairs sequentially;     however, not as an array of objects

  });
  options.series[0].data = data;
  console.log(options.series[0].data);  // only getting the last k:v pair and the chart     doesn't render
});

console.log(options.series[0].data);  // an empty array []
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

});
```

Again, thank you in advance for your help with this.  I've been working on it for days.

Comment: you are dealing with an async issue, you are trying to use `series[0].data` before it has been set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$.getJSON(url, function (series) {
  options.series[0].data = $.map(series, function(val) {
      return { name: val.name, y: parseFloat(val.pc1) };
  });

  new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

**Update** fix your existing `each` loop

```
$.getJSON(url, function (series) {
  var data = [];

  $.each(series, function(val) {
      data.push({ name: val.name, y: parseFloat(val.pc1) });
  });

  options.series[0].data = data;
  new Highcharts.Chart(options);
});
```

Comment: Thank you!  It's now working.  Can you please explain why $.map() works and $.each() doesn't?

Comment: the way you use `data` is wrong in your `each` loop. In `data = [];`, `data` is a global var since you didn't declare it locally, the line is same as `window.data = [];`. This line reset `data` to empty array for every loop, the final result is the `data` array only hold the last `val_i`. To fix it, declare `data` as a local variable outside of `each` loop.

Comment: Thank you again!  I really appreciate your help.  I only started coding last fall.  I knew there was a "scope" issue but couldn't resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like:

```
var jsonArray = yourArray.map(function(item) { return JSON.stringify(item); });
```

will handle the conversion to JSON for you.